# mod_rewrite, how to quantifier path parts

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have to convert this url and remove a part of the path:

```
    http://myhost.com/cw/es/extrapath --> http://myhost.com/es/extrapath
```

I tried this:

```
    RewriteRule ^/(ew|ww|es|cw)/(es|en)/^(.*)$ http://myhost.com/es/$2/$3
```

And this:

```
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]??)/(es|en)/^(.*)$ http://myhost.com/es/$2/$3
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong in these .htaccess lines?